# rewriting function for incoming calls in sipml5

Tags: javascript, function, webrtc, pjsip

Hi guys I want to rewrite incoming call part from official guide sipml5. I want to create separate function without html elements. Below you can find my codes. The button triggers function when the call is coming, but I want to create separate function without html elements and use this function inside of my code.

Here is incoming call case statement:

```
 case 'i_new_call':
    {
        if (oSipSessionCall) {
            // do not accept the incoming call if we're already 'in call'
            e.newSession.hangup(); // comment this line for multi-line support
        }
        else {
            oSipSessionCall = e.newSession;
            oSipSessionCall.setConfiguration(oConfigCall);
            uiBtnReceive('Answer');
            startRingTone();

            var sRemoteNumber = (oSipSessionCall.getRemoteFriendlyName() || 'unknown');
            txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "<i>Incoming call from [<b>" + sRemoteNumber + "</b>]</i>";
            showNotifICall(sRemoteNumber);
        }
        break;
```

And the function is:

```
function uiBtnReceive(m_text) {
    if (m_text == "Answer") {
        btnAccept.value = btnAccept.innerHTML = m_text;
        btnAccept.onclick = function () { sipCall('call-audio'); };
    }
}
```

My problem here is when I am not using button onclick the function is triggered them-self. Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem and would like write this maybe will be useful for someone. My issue was when I called function without any event, the incoming calls accepted directly without calling function ( My main problem was avoiding from human action). But the problem is that you will get browser error each time if you will not use any event handler here.